# Ruby readline completion with comment

Tags: ruby, autocomplete, readline, command-line-interface

I'm planning on writing a CLI in ruby which supports tab completion.

Given the `readline` example from [ruby-doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/readline/rdoc/Readline.html):

```
require 'readline'

LIST = [
  'search', 'download', 'open',
  'help', 'history', 'quit',
  'url', 'next', 'clear',
  'prev', 'past'
].sort

comp = proc { |s| LIST.grep(/^#{Regexp.escape(s)}/) }

Readline.completion_append_character = " "
Readline.completion_proc = comp

while line = Readline.readline('> ', true)
  p line
end
```

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to show the autocomplete options with a comment, like git does, such that the first column is the autocompelte itself and the second one is a comment explaining the function:

```
» git w [TAB]                                         
whatchanged         -- show commit-logs and differences they introduce
write-tree          -- create tree from the current index
```

Right now, I'm able to add a comment, however it is part of the autocomplete.

Is it possible using `readline` or other module?

Comment: I've never seen readline completing commands as you showed in the example with git, maybe are you using zsh?

Comment: My bad. It is zsh. However, is it still possible with ruby's `realine`?

Comment: No, readline is not capable of such amazing things. :-)